# Python Web-scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to return the string value when attribute matches a particular value in tag. On running the below code I am not getting any value.In fact I want to fetch all the string( i.e. Overcast with Haze, 39°F, 4°C) based on the "class" attribute value "myforecast-current", "myforecast-current-lrg" and "myforecast-current-sm" respectively. Pl help with correct code

```
if soup.p['class'] == 'myforecast-current-lrg':
   print(soup.p.string)
```

```html
<div id="current_conditions-summary" class="pull-left" >
                        <img src="newimages/large/ovc.png" alt="" class="pull-left" />
                        <p class="myforecast-current">Overcast with Haze</p>
            <p class="myforecast-current-lrg">39&deg;F</p>
            <p class="myforecast-current-sm">4&deg;C</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: you code returns Overcast with Haze

39°F

4°C.  What is the output you are expecting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to understand how `BeautifulSoup` finds elements.

I know this method, I think there should be other methods.

```py
for data in soup.find_all('p', class_='myforecast-current-lrg'):
    print(data.string)
```

or

```
for data in soup.find_all('p'):
    if 'myforecast-current-lrg' in data['class']:
        print(data.string)
```

Comment: First one one worked, thanks...Also If temperature of  different is cities fetched on each respective click, is there a way I can extract temperature of all cities from single html file or do I need to get html file for each of the city and pass it through beautifulsoup? Hope you got my question

Comment: An html file contains the temperature of the city, then you can get the temperature of all cities at once.